# Transfer OS X Dashboard Widgets Between Computers

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, data-transfer, dashboard-widget

Can anyone tell me an easy way to transfer my dashboard widgets from one OS X computer to another?  If there was a way to keep their positioning/settings too that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Widgets are saved at `/Library/Widgets/` and `/Users/[user]/Library/Widgets/`

If you copy `/Users/[user]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.plist` that will copy your Dashboard configuration.

Each widget will have it's own configuration file in `/Users/[user]/Library/Preferences/`, for example `widget-com.apple.widget.weather.plist`

Comment: thanks for the work!  I'll try copying those files/folders and see what happens

Comment: still working on it.  copying didn't work automatically but I haven't restarted yet.  don't worry, I didn't forget :)

Comment: @wajiw you can restart the Dock/Dashboard by `killall -HUP Dock` at a terminal

Comment: nice, that works.  I had to re-add the widgets but they were there and had the same prefs.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

macOS does not have the `/Users/[user]/Library/Widgets/` folder on a fresh install. Simply create the `Widgets` folder and place your widget file in it. Your widget will appear in the Dashboard.